# Angular 2 and .NET Web API Authentication

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

What is the best way to have a username and password authentication system that works between Angular 2 and .NET Web API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all try to avoid using self implemented methods.
Most commonly used approach is to use `Json web token`.
https://jwt.io/
There for when you log in, return Token to angular2 and then pass it on every request.
There are many examples of implementation and libraries to be used.
https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt

[How to use JWT in MVC application for authentication and authorization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791499/how-to-use-jwt-in-mvc-application-for-authentication-and-authorization)

Answer (score 1):

Best way is using a package called IdentityServer. I have written a tutorial on it but using one of its older versions, however it will give you a good idea:

[Securing .Net Core Web API with IdentityServer4 (Resource Owner flow); using SQL Server db, enabling refresh tokens and external login - Part 1](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/securing-net-core-web-api-identityserver4-resource-owner-dalvandi)