# Accessing an Azure AD secured Web App View with Token

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

We have a requirement to allow a third party to authenticate to an Azure Web App and display an Azure AD secured Web App View non interactively.

The problem I am encountering is I can get a token, but when I try to request the required resource in Azure Web App with the token, I am getting a Page saying to **Sign into my Account** instead of the HTML content from Azure Web App.

I had developed the code following steps from the below picture

```
string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
string tenant = "xxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
string clientId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);
Uri redirectUri = new Uri(@"http://xxxxxDaemonAppDev");
string resourcePath = @"https://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/Customer/CashSummary?term=xxxxxx";
string appIdURI = @"https://xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/WebApp-xxxxx.azurewebsites.net";
AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
AuthenticationResult result = null;

authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new FileCache());
UserCredential uc = new UserPasswordCredential("xxxx@jkintranet.com", "xxx@xxxx");

try
{
    //I am getting the Token here.
    result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(appIdURI, clientId, uc).Result;


    #region Call Web APP

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(resourcePath).Result;


    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //I am not getting the HTML Content here
        string rezstring = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var todoArray = JArray.Parse(rezstring);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        foreach (var todo in todoArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(todo["Title"]);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
    return;
}
```

Tools and Technologies followed:

1. Client App is a [Daemon or Server Application to Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api)
2. Server App is a Web Azure Web App Secured with Azure AD authentication
3. Both Server as *Web APP* and Client as *Native* are registered in Azure AD

The Architecture I followed:

[image]

Following the steps, I have written the code

The Web App's StartupAuth.cs has this:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            AppUserModelContext appUserDB = new AppUserModelContext();

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            //Changed this from
            //app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            //Changed this to
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                //added this
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
                CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager()
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = Authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                    UseTokenLifetime = false,
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {

                        // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var code = context.Code;
                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                            string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                            //AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                            //code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);
                            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                            code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },

                        SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                        {
                            var identity = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                            var identityName = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name").Value;
                            var aIdentity = identityName.Split('@');
                            var appUser = appUserDB.Find(aIdentity[0]);

                            if (appUser == null)
                            {
                                context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri = "/Account/SignOut";
                            }

                            //Add Claims-Company
                            context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(
                                new System.Security.Claims.Claim(
                                        "http://com.jksb.org/claims/customclaims/company",
                                        "JKB",
                                        null,
                                        "LOCAL AUTHORITY"));

                            //Add Claims-Business Unit
                            context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(
                                new System.Security.Claims.Claim(
                                        "http://com.jksb.org/claims/customclaims/buid",
                                        appUser.AppBuID,
                                        null,
                                        "LOCAL AUTHORITY"));


                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },

                        //added this
                        AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                        {
                            if (context.Exception.Message.StartsWith("OICE_20004") || context.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX10311"))
                            {
                                context.SkipToNextMiddleware();
                                return Task.FromResult(0);
                            }
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }

                    },
        }
```

Comment: When this happened to me, it turned out the web application wasn't well configured to validate JWTs from Azure, so please post that

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I am kind of novice, please let me know what you want me to post?

Comment: The code used in the web app to configure Azure authentication

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have updated the Azure Authentication of my Service App

Comment: In order to *validate* tokens from azure you need to use the JWT middleware, not the `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` one

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Is JWT for ASP.NET core? Mine is a native ASP.NET App; What would be the package I need to install?

Comment: No, it's not. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791499/how-to-use-jwt-in-mvc-application-for-authentication-and-authorization)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thank you for helping me throughout! Let me go through this.