# MVC client app consuming ASP.NET Core web api Authorization problem?

Tags: c#, authentication, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-webapi

I have web ASP.net core web api and MVC client app and i want to authorize with JWT token.  I found tones of tutorials  webapi + jwt + angular but cant find any for my situation. I get token from api but i don't know how to send it back with requests for api to know that I am authorized. Please give me some pointers or suggest tutorial how to achieve this.

Comment: Though it doesn't exactly match, following link has an example to help you to start with. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791499/how-to-use-jwt-in-mvc-application-for-authentication-and-authorization

Comment: Do i need to use javascript for every link?

Comment: @ValentinaDijakovićKukec: You just need to pass token with requests inside the Authorization header. `Authorization : Bearer token`. If you are using `HttpClient` inside your controllers, just add header with token there.