# how do i make a login interface with MVC and also secure it with JWT authentication?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm quite new to MVC and JWT, I've made some research on MVC and also JWT but mvc uses .net and JWT uses .net core api, how do i utilize them together?

Answer (score 0):

I attached some links below that might be helpful:

[JWT authentication for ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281050/jwt-authentication-for-asp-net-web-api)

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/webapi-owin/01-authorization

[How to use JWT in MVC application for authentication and authorization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791499/how-to-use-jwt-in-mvc-application-for-authentication-and-authorization)