# Asp.net MVC (not core) application needs to receive a JWT from a mobile app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jwt

I have a requirement that has me a little baffled.  A client has an app that allows it's customers to view it's account and billing statements.  In the past the app invoked a web page on my web server built on an ASP.NET application that allowed the user to enter his credit card information and the web app processed the payment with the payment gateway.

Now the client requires that the payment page require authentication.  Since the app uses JWT authentication when connecting to it's own services, the idea is to provide the JWT to the ASP.NET application so that we can verify that the call is authenticated and read some information from it.  But I can't find any way for a regular ASP.NET MVC 5 web app to read a JWT that comes from somewhere else.

Has anyone seen anything like this?  Anyone has any pointers for me to look at?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791499/how-to-use-jwt-in-mvc-application-for-authentication-and-authorization . Maybe it will help to start.

Comment: Are you talking about something like [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/)? The post mentions it works in non-Core also.